# NodeJS: serialport parser.on() not working, can't read buffer

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, serial-port, raspbian

All of the answers I found are for the old API, and I can't get the [current documentation](https://serialport.io/docs/api-parser-readline) working.

I am trying to read serial data from a Raspberry Pi GPIO. Here is the code:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline')

const port = new SerialPort('/dev/serial0', {
  baudRate: 9600
})

port.open(() => {
  console.log("port open"); 
})

port.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Data:', data)               // <----- This code works
})

const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' }))

parser.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

The `port.on()` works when I get serial data. However, the `parser.on()` does not i.e. reading the buffer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the delimiter is found on the data received directly to the `port.on(data` callback?